# React native app builds successfully but doesn't work

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

I have an app in React Native, version `0.69.7`, and it has stopped working. The build builds successfully and the application opens but nothing is displayed.

[image]

I downgraded to version `0.68.5` and it worked again, but when the upgrade is done again to version `0.69` or `higher`, the same thing happens.

I upgraded following the [React Native Upgrade Helper](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/).

Metro Bundle also does not display logs, and no internet connection related operations work within the app.

Note: The black screen in the print is where an update via Codepush should happen, but it hangs there due to the app not being able to make the request.

This problem only happens on Android.

Any idea what could be causing this?

```
Environment:
React Native: 0.69.7
OS Version: 10.0.0
OS: Android
Gradle Plugin Version: 7.1.1
Gradle Version: 7.3.0
JDK Version: 10.0.16
JRE Version: 1.8.0_341
```

Comment: Have you tried to `gradlew clean` in the android folder and remove application from simulator and rerun it again?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately it didn't work.